# Is it possible to present modals with the UIModalPresentationPageSheet or UIModalPresentationFormSheet style with react-navigation (v5)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle?language=objc), presenting a modal on iOS 13 defaults to the `UIModalPresentationAutomatic`, which typically maps to the `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` style.

Similarly, react-native-screens [appears to support](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/master/ios/RNSScreen.m#L345) the various options, but I've so far been unable to determine if it's possible pass this with react-navigation, or if react-navigation is using this code path at all. react-native-screens [appears to default](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/master/ios/RNSScreen.m#L76) to `UIModalPresentationAutomatic`, which leads me to believe react-navigation is doing something else entirely.

Is it possible to present these `Stack.Screen` components using these smaller modal types within a `Stack.Navigator`?

Here is a simple React Native app that demonstrates the issue.

```js
import "react-native-gesture-handler"
import * as React from "react"
import { Button, View, Text } from "react-native"
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack"
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        mode="modal"
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          stackPresentation: "formSheet",
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App
```

Regardless of the specified `stackPresentation`, it is always presented as a full screen modal. How can I get `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You "just" need to use the `createNativeStackNavigator` function directly from `react-native-screens`. The [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/) actually have a section describing how to set it up.

For your example app above you'd simply need to import the two functions needed and change your stack initialization to look like this

```js
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from 'react-native-screens/native-stack'
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens'

enableScreens()
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
```

Then set the appropriate `screenOptions` in your `Stack.Navigator` component.

```js
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  screenOptions={{ 
    headerShown: false, 
    stackPresentation: 'formSheet' 
  }}
>
```